# Table expands with inner content

Tags: html, html-table

How do you prevent a td to grow wider than the table max-width? I cannot set the size in pixels, as it is used to fill up the rest of the width of the table. And when I set max-width to 100% this seems to be its content width.

```
<div class="content" style="width: 200px; max-width: 200px;">
    <table class="outer-table" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="white-space: nowrap; max-width: 100%; background-color: yellow;">
                <div class="inner-div" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%; overflow: scroll;">
                This is a table width to much content. I use "white-space: nowrap" to force it to grow wide.
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/TxqT4/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove `white-space: nowrap` from your td style

using nowrap property you are forcing td content to stay inline ie. no line break that's why it is creating the problem

See here [Update code](http://jsfiddle.net/TxqT4/3/)

Comment: I use the nowrap on purpose. But why does not the "overflow: scroll" take effect? Because it seems as if the td's 100% width is not the tables width as I would expect.

Comment: @einord i got your problem. so just add overflow:scroll or auto to parent div. it will solve your problem have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/TxqT4/4/. please respond whenever you get it.